# python - Variable scope after using a 'with' statement

Tags: python, file, scope

I didn't find the answer for this question on stackoverflow, so I thought it might be helpful to ask it, and have it here -

I am declaring a new dictionary after I open a file, in the following way -

```
with open('some_file.txt','r') as f:
    dict = json.loads(f.read()) #converts text to a dictionary
```

my question is - will I be able to reach dict content's even after the 'with' scope ends.

Thanks

Comment: Why not try it out and see?

Comment: 1) thought would be helpful to have it here for others 2) also looking for why it is the way it is (i.e. why is it different from the variable's scope inside the 'if' statements for example)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, in Python the [scope](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) of a variable ends only when the code block it's defined in ends, and the `with` statement is not a code block per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/executionmodel.html):

> The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class
>   definition. Each command typed interactively is a block. A script file
>   (a file given as standard input to the interpreter or specified as a
>   command line argument to the interpreter) is a code block. A script
>   command (a command specified on the interpreter command line with the
>   ‘-c’ option) is a code block. The string argument passed to the
>   built-in functions eval() and exec() is a code block.

Answer (score 1):

In python scope is defined by functions. There is no indentation scope (similar to "bracket" scope in other languages). The `with` part affects just the `f` object.

Comment: The `with` statement only *assigns* to `f`, introducing the name into the current containing scope if necessary. The name remains in scope after the `with` statement completes.

Comment: @chepner: yes, but exiting the context manager *affects* the object assigned to `f`. I didn't say it disappears

Answer (score -1):

Yes you will, you will not be able to access `f`, everything else is fair game.

Comment: `f` remains in scope. The underlying file is closed, but in general whatever object is bound by the `as` keyword in the `with` statement remains available after the `with`, until the end of the enclosing block.